# Asymptotic analysis of functions

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, complexity-theory, asymptotic-complexity

I have the following function to prove that its time complexity is less or equal to O(xlogx)

**f(x) =xlogx+3logx2**

I need some help to solve this.

Comment: I need to solve this to prove

Comment: @user3572213 What to solve? (x+6)logx is O(xlogx)??

Comment: I did understand your solution but how you have made x log x > = 6 log x ?

Comment: i have another function to prove , if you can help me out in that also ?

Comment: Please post that as a separate question! @user3572213.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given,

```
   f(x) = xlogx+3logx^2
        = xlogx+6logx   // since log (a^b) = b log a
```

As we know, ***f(x) = O(g(x)), if | f(x) | <= M. | g(x) |, where M is a positive real number***.

Therefore, for M>=7 and x varying in the real positive range,

```
M . x log x >= x log x + 6 log x
            >= (x+6) log x.

f(x) = x log x + 3log x^2 
     = O(x log x).
```